# Fixed Navbar doesn't stop at right position when scrolling

Tags: html, css, scroll, navbar

I've created a fixed Navbar on the top of the page that automatically scrolls to certain sections of the webpage. However, it doesn't stop at the right position, it's always scrolls a little too far off the section beginning. I need it to stop exaclty so that the navbar connects with the beginning of the new selected section.

```css
@viewport {
  width: device-width;
  zoom: 1.0;
}

html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

:root {
  --base-color: #383E4C;
  --box-color: #F2F2F2;
  --border-color: #808080;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: white;
  font-family: 'Cabin', Arial, sans-serif;
}


/* homepage section */

#navbar {
  background-color: var(--base-color);
  width: 100%;
  height: 110px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

#navbar ul {
  list-style: none;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  text-align: center;
}

#navbar ul li {
  display: inline;
  font-size: 20px;
  border: 1px solid var(--border-color);
  padding: 18px 26px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

#navbar ul li:hover {
  background-color: #646d7c;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

#navbar a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

#banner {
  margin-top: 110px;
}

#banner img {
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.banner-image {
  position: relative;
}

.banner-items {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}


/* about section */

.about-container {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 800px;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.infobox {
  background-color: var(--box-color);
  border: 1px solid var(--border-color);
  margin: 1px;
  width: 15%;
  height: 60%;
  margin: 80px 40px;
}

.about-container2 {
  margin-top: -200px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 800px;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.infobox2 {
  background-color: var(--box-color);
  border: 1px solid var(--border-color);
  margin: 1px;
  width: 30%;
  height: 60%;
  margin: 80px 40px;
}

.infobox img {
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.infobox2 img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 45%;
}

.infobox p {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  text-align: left;
}

.infobox2 p {
  padding: 20px 40px;
}

.infobox button {
  height: 40px;
  width: 80px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 20px;
  color: white;
  background-color: var(--base-color);
}

.infobox button:hover {
  height: 45px;
  width: 85px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.25s;
}


/* service */

#services-banner {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  margin-top: -150px;
}

#services-banner h1 {
  color: white;
  font-size: 50px;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px black;
}

.services-image {
  position: relative;
}

.services-items {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#services-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 800px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en" id="top">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" media="screen" />
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Cabin:wght@600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

  <title>Website Template</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="navbar">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#top">Homepage</a></li>
      <li><a href="#about-us">About Us</a></li>
      <li><a href="#services-banner">Services</a></li>
      <li>Contact</li>
      <li>External</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="banner" class="banner-image" style="margin-top: 110px">
    <img src="images/banner-mountains.jpg" alt="banner" />
    <div class="banner-items">
      <h1 style="font-size: 50px">Homepage Title</h1>
      <p style="font-size: 20px">Some long space filling text here</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="about-us" class="about-container">
    <div class="infobox">
      <img src="images/city.jpg" alt="city">
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
        in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
      </p>
      <button>Button</button>
    </div>
    <div class="infobox">
      <img src="images/lake.jpg" alt="lake">
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
        in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
      </p>
      <button>Button</button>
    </div>
    <div class="infobox">
      <img src="images/road.jpg" alt="road">
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
        in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
      </p>
      <button>Button</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="about-us2" class="about-container2">
    <div class="infobox2">
      <img src="images/forest.jpg" alt="forest">
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
        in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
        <br><br> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Suscipit adipiscing bibendum est ultricies integer quis auctor elit.
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="infobox2">
      <img src="images/bridge.jpg" alt="bridge">
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
        in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
        <br><br> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Suscipit adipiscing bibendum est ultricies integer quis auctor elit.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="services-banner" class="services-image">
    <img src="images/banner-services.jpg" alt="services-banner">
    <div class="services-items">
      <h1>Services</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="services-container">

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: what do you mean scrolls to certain sections? could you provide an example of what you are specifically trying to achieve?

Comment: `fixed position` means, that it will be outside of the actual flow. In combination with `anchor` targeting it will eb always off. the `anchor` targeting will move the targeted element always to the very top of the viewport unless you use a JS script to offset it.

Comment: @JoshKatofsky the OP is using a technique called `anchor` you use a link with: `<a href="#id"></a>`. Using `#id` as a `hyper reference` instead of a normal link path will move the page to a specific element with that `ID`. Normally it would instantly jump to that section unless you use this css line: `html { scroll-behavior: smooth; }` which will then scroll instead of jumping. You can also use that in combination with `:target` selector in css.

Answer (score 1):

Additional to my first answer:

Indeed there is a (for me) newer technique now to prevent the page to scroll behind fixed headers using anchor links. Just add to the anchored section one line of css:

```
.anchored-section {
    scroll-margin-top: 110px;  /* value = height of fixed header */
}
```

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-margin-top

---

**UPDATE:**

Seems that this indeed is a newer technique which is not implemented in all Browsers yet. As actual Chrome, Firefox and Edge and others support it there seems to an issue with Safari! As of `canIuse.com` for Safari should be used the atrribute `scroll-snap-margin-top` instead of `scroll-margin-top`.

Please check yourself: https://caniuse.com/?search=scroll-margin-top

Answer (score 0):

The scrolling behaviour of your code is correct: it moves the anchored section to the top of the page. Unfortunately fixed header covers the upper parts of the sections in that case. As I know you cannot change this special scrolling behaviour without js up to now .

One simple technique to fix it with HTML/CSS is to work with separated anchor elements on the top of the anchored sections.

Add an additional empty div to the beginning of every anchored section. Move anchor id to that div. Than shift the div with a relative positioning as far to the top as your header has height.

Notes:

- With this technique you should not use the anchor id's for other css styling.
- If you have a responsive page with different heights for the header you need to adapt the value for the positioning of the anchor positioning for every different responsive view.

Here a short EXPLAINING snippet just to explain the technique. You can add that easily to your code for all sections.

EXPLAINING snippet HTML:

```
<div  class="about-container">
   <div id="about-us" class="menu-anchor"><!-- empty anchor element --></div>
   This is an anchored section.
   ... your html ...
</div>
```

EXPLAINING snippet CSS:

```
.menu-anchor {
   position: relative;
   top: -110px /* value = height of fixed header */
}
```

Comment: Holla ... I have been to fast ... and obviously my knowledge has not been up to date in this case ;-) I added a second answer with a more easier css only technique.